# How to design a web ERP software for school using ASP.net and mysql

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, erp

I have to design a school web ERP for a client of mine.
The following modules need to be present as of now:  
      Student 
      Inventory 
      Cafeteria  
      Admissions

Please help me with the required links or book which can guide me with the steps that need to be followed to create the design. Difference between different designs that can be used for e.g. in one of the links i read that Component based design should be used.

Also, Please note that the modules need to be licensed. i.e. The user must be able to choose one or more modules of his interest and only those modules should be installed.

I am new to this area and this exercise is primarily for learning process so I WANT TO DO THIS FROM SCRATCH AND NOT USE THE EXISTING OPEN SOURCE AT THIS POINT OF TIME.

Please help me with the required links / books / papers etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is way too broad to be completely answered with a single post. But if you're looking for a book to explore architectural approaches I can highly recommend the following, which in my opinion is a must-read for every developer anyway:

[**Patterns of Enterprise Architecture**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) by Martin Fowler

Comment: Thank you Dennis for sharing this. 
Any other links / blogs / discussions related to the development of a web ERP would also be helpful.